# How to remove half of the elements in a std::list?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am currently trying to make it so that when the snake collides with this poison food, half of what is in this list is removed.

```
void PlayerSnake::update()
{
    poison_.update();

    int Node_remover_ = Psnake_parts_.size() / 2;

    if (x_ == poison_.x_ && y_ == poison_.y_) {
        Psnake_parts_.remove(Node_remover_);

        //prg::application.exit();
    }
}
```

The code I have here isnt currently working. I want to know what function I would need to use of the `std::list` to make it so that half of what is in this list is removed.

Comment: what is your question, and what is the problem?

Comment: The code I have here isnt currently working. I want to know what function I would need to use of the stl list to make it so that half of what is in this list is removed.

Comment: You are asking for the way of deleting few elements from vector? Which data structure you are working with?

Comment: "isn't working" is not accurate enough.

Comment: You could just walk the list and remove every even or odd node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>**Note:** the implementation examples in this post assumes that the initial half is what should be saved, if you'd like to only keep what is in the tail a few adjustments must be made.</sub>

---

#### THE SIMPLE IMPLEMENTATION

Even though one can use the erase member-function of `std::list` to erase elements a far simpler approach is to use `resize` with the current `size` divided in half.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
```

```
std::list<int> lst { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

lst.resize ((lst.size () + 1) / 2);

for (auto& elem : lst)
    std::cout << elem << " ";
```

```
1 2 3
```

<sup>**Note:** the reason for `lst.size () + 1` is that we in cases where the total of elements isn't even, we would like to keep the bigger "half part". In this case we'd rather save three elements, instead of two.</sup>

---

**THE COMMON IMPLEMENTATION**

```
#include <iterator>

...

auto position = lst.begin ();

std::advance (position, (lst.size () + 1) / 2);

lst.erase (position, lst.end ());

...
```

You might ask yourself why this piece of code looks mad ugly, and the reason is rather simple: We can't write it as a single expression since the iterators of `std::list` are only *bidirectional*, not *random access*.

This means that an iterator can't change the location where it's referring to by more than one step at a time, which is why we are using `std::advance`.

Answer (score -1):

```
halflength = myvector.size()/2;
myvector.erase (myvector.begin(),myvector.begin()+halflength);
```

Try above. You can end at `myvector.end()` for 2nd half.
Hope it will help.

Comment: Do stl::list work the same way as vectors?

Comment: **-1**: No, the above won't compile since the iterators of `std::list` is not *random-access*.